# Strange Loop Behavior when using List

Tags: python, praw

i did a little research here at stackoverflow, but could not find anything... maybe because I dont really know what to look for. 
I wrote a script to add reddit comments (from one of the submissions) to wordpress. Everything is fine and work without any problems... however there is a strange behavior within loop I completely dont understand.
Let start with example code (it is a part of function called "generuj"):

```
komment = WordPressComment()
mySubmissionId = submission.id
komentarze = r.get_submission(submission_id=mySubmissionId)
komentarze.replace_more_comments(limit=0, threshold=1)
flat_comments = praw.helpers.flatten_tree(komentarze.comments)
```

above code does not matter, but I put this for better understanding
there are different number of comments with every submission, but no more
than 200.. so sometimes there are few like 5, sometimes i.e. 184
they are stored in flat_comments

```
    listaKomentarzy = []
    for comment in flat_comments:
        if (str(comment.body).__len__() > 20 and str(comment.body).__len__() < 50 and not 'sometestword' in str(comment.body)):
        try:
            listaKomentarzy.append(str(comment.body))

        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            print e

        else:
            print (Fore.RED + Style.DIM + "wrong comment")


print len(listaKomentarzy) #to be sure that all comments are in listaKomentarzy

longKom = max(listaKomentarzy, key=len)
indeks = listaKomentarzy.index(longKom)
del listaKomentarzy[indeks]
```

here I remove the longest comment and it works... so at this point everything is still or at least look like is working fine.
however the nightmare starts here:

```
for row in listaKomentarzy:
    komment.content = row
    print row
```

the above code is a part of function called generuj, which is also run in for loop which goes through every submission (and then gets new comments every run)
to simplify this code runs function:

```
generuj()
del listaKomentarzy
```

i use del listaKomentarzy to be sure that is empty every time the loop starts
so my problem is as follows:

```
for row in listaKomentarzy:
    komment.content = row
    print row
```

script is working, everything is working fine... script is printing every comment (print row) as it should be... but sometimes it does not. There must be something strange with comment, with list or something, I have no idea what exacly.. my first thought was that there is a limit of how many comments may be stored in python list, but I found that there could be much much more than I store in listaKomentarzy (around 200 max).

I dont know what my cause breaking the for loop. The only thing is changing are comments. To explain it better I will show you example.
Lets say there are 5 submissions, 
first has 10 comments, 
second has 20 comments,
third has 30 comments,
fourth has 40 comments,
fifth has 50 comments,

I run a script, it load 10 comments from submission1 and print:
comment1, comment2, comment3... comment10 
then code does clear the list of comments in listaKomentarzy
takes submission2 and load 20 comments and print:
comment1, comment2, comment3....comment20
then code does clear and load 30 comments for submission3 and then
nothing happen (it does not print even one comment) breaks the loop and 
load submission4 with 40 comments and print all 40 comments without a problem
then it loads submission5 with 50 comments and breaks without printing

(no errors, no info in server logs)
I have no idea where to start again with this code...
anyone could help please?

Comment: Just a feeling but you might be running into unicode errors. That's sometimes the way with intermittent bugs on web content.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer
there was a problem with encoding, but in completely different place than I tought

I had to change

```
str(comment.body).__len__()
```

to
    str(comment.body.encode('ascii', 'ignore')).**len**()